# Would two sequence that converge also produce a converging limit

Tags: limits

If two sequences Ax and Bx converge than would they also always produce a sequence that converges when divided together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true ... consider $a_n=1$ and $b_n = \frac1n$.

If, however, the limit of $b_n$ is nonzero, then $a_n/b_n$ [will converge](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/limit-product-quotient-laws-for-convergent-sequences).

Comment: Doesn't this confirm what the OP is asking? I think what you mean to say is take $b_n$ to converge to 0, then the ratio $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ does not converge.

Comment: @AnthonyP The OP's assertion is true under the additional constraint that $\lim b_n$ is nonzero. "Not true" applies to the assertion as stated.

Comment: I see... thanks for the clarification.